# Laravel app not printing invoice while using from IPAD

Tags: php, ipad, printing

I have developed a Laravel app. We have an invoice printing option, but it's not working when I am using it via Ipad, not connecting to the printer. another app on the same iPad prints fine. The print option works when I am using Windows OS

I have tried various options but have not succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried running your app in different browsers?

Comment: @petersowah Yes, same issue